# Improving my R code - advice wanted on better way of coding?

Tags: r

I have code that is working, its a webscraping script that first gets from URLs from a webpage and then uses a for loop to run through all URLs. During the loop it takes some information and saves it to a data frame that I first create as an empty data frame before the loop. The process uses rbind and works fine.

However, I feel this code is not optimal and there maybe a package, I think the solution will be lapply... maybe not. But I was hoping someone could give me a pointer to a better way of coding this (if that exists) and how it could be implemented.

```
library(rvest)

URL <- "http://www.transfermarkt.com/premier-league/startseite/wettbewerb/GB1"

WS <- read_html(URL)

URLs <- WS %>% html_nodes(".hide-for-pad .vereinprofil_tooltip") %>% html_attr("href") %>% as.character()
URLs <- paste0("http://www.transfermarkt.com",URLs)

Catcher1 <- data.frame(Player=character(),P_URL=character())

for (i in URLs) {
  
  WS1 <- read_html(i)
  Player <- WS1 %>% html_nodes("#yw1 .spielprofil_tooltip") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()
  P_URL <- WS1 %>% html_nodes("#yw1 .spielprofil_tooltip") %>% html_attr("href") %>% as.character()
  temp <- data.frame(Player,P_URL)
  Catcher1 <- rbind(Catcher1,temp)
  cat("*")
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be moved to code review stackexchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `purrr` instead of the loop as follows:

```
require(rvest)
require(purrr)
require(tibble)

URLs %>% 
  map(read_html) %>% 
  map(html_nodes, "#yw1 .spielprofil_tooltip") %>% 
  map_df(~tibble(Player = html_text(.), P_URL = html_attr(., "href")))
```

Timing:

```
   user  system elapsed 
  2.939   2.746   5.699
```

The step that take the most time is the crawling via `map(read_html)`.
To paralyze that you can use e.g. the parallel backend of `plyr` as follows:

```
require(httr)
doMC::registerDoMC(cores=3) # cores depending on your system
plyr::llply(URLs, GET, .parallel = TRUE) %>% 
  map(read_html) %>% 
  map(html_nodes, "#yw1 .spielprofil_tooltip") %>% 
  map_df(~tibble(Player = html_text(.), P_URL = html_attr(., "href")))
```

Somehow my Rstudio crashed using `plyr::llply(URLs, read_html, .parallel = TRUE)` thats why i use the underlying `httr::GET` and parse the result in the next step via `map(read_html)`. So the scraping is done in parallel but the parsing of the response is done sequentially.

Timing:

```
   user  system elapsed 
  2.505   0.337   2.940
```

In both cases the result looks as follows:

```
# A tibble: 1,036 × 2
          Player                                P_URL
           <chr>                                <chr>
1   David de Gea   /david-de-gea/profil/spieler/59377
2      D. de Gea   /david-de-gea/profil/spieler/59377
3  Sergio Romero  /sergio-romero/profil/spieler/30690
4      S. Romero  /sergio-romero/profil/spieler/30690
5  Sam Johnstone /sam-johnstone/profil/spieler/110864
6   S. Johnstone /sam-johnstone/profil/spieler/110864
7    Daley Blind    /daley-blind/profil/spieler/12282
8       D. Blind    /daley-blind/profil/spieler/12282
9    Eric Bailly   /eric-bailly/profil/spieler/286384
10     E. Bailly   /eric-bailly/profil/spieler/286384
# ... with 1,026 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks Floo0, some excellent ideas. If the CSS identifier  "#yw1 .spielprofil_tooltip" was different for the scraped data would that change your choice?

Comment: In your example all the information is based on a single CSS identifier. Thats why it is so easy. If there were more identifiers involved i would most likely use a separate function that takes in a document and returns the dataframe i want. E.g. in your code taking `WS1` as input and returning `temp`.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you are growing an object. In this case, you are growing a data frame. To solve this problem, create a large data frame **before** the loop, and fill it in. Whether this is the bottleneck, it's hard to tell. If the `length(URLs)` is small, then it won't make much of a difference.

Another possible speed up is to run your loop in parallel. Perhaps using `parallel::parSapply`. To convert your loop to a parallel version, just move the "loop" part to a function and you code will become something like:

```
parallel::parSapply(1:URLs, get_resource)
```

Alternatively you could try the [foreach](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/index.html) package.

Comment: Thanks, been looking into foreach and making some progress