# R return multiple nodes in 1 search using rvest (massive list of urls)

Tags: r, rvest

I am using rvest to scrape a website. It works, buy highly inefficient, and I can't figure out how to get it to work better.

in url is a list of over 10.000 url's.

```
number <- sapply(url, function(x)
  read_html(x) %>%
  html_nodes(".js-product-artnr") %>%
  html_text())

price_new <- sapply(url, function(x)
  read_html(x) %>%
  html_nodes(".product-page__price__new") %>%
  html_text())

price_old <- sapply(url, function(x)
  read_html(x) %>%
  html_nodes(".product-page__price__old") %>%
  html_text())
```

The problem above is, rvest visits the 10.000 urls to get the first node in ".js-product-artnr", then visits the same 10.000 urls again for the second node and so on. In the end I expect to need about 10 different nodes from these 10.000 pages. getting them 1 by 1 and combining into a data frame later on takes way to long, there must be a better way.

I am looking for something like below, to get all information in 1 search

```
info <- sapply(url, function(x)
  read_html(x) %>%
  html_nodes(".js-product-artnr") %>%
  html_nodes(".product-page__price__new") %>%
  html_nodes(".product-page__price__old") %>%
  html_text())
```

Comment: Just save the first result to a variable `page<-read_html(x)`, then do all the extractions `page %>% html_nodes(".js-product-artnr") %>% html_text(); page %>% html_nodes(".product-page__price__new") %>% html_text()` etc. It's unclear to me from your example exactly what data structure you expect the results to be in.

Comment: Maybe this answer of mine to a similar problem helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685989/improving-my-r-code-advice-wanted/39686263#39686263

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
  func <- function(url){
  sample <- read_html(url) %>%
  scrape1 <- html_nodes(sample, ".js-product-artnr")%>%
  html_text()
  scrape2 <- html_nodes(sample, ".product-page__price__new") %>%
  html_text()
  scrape3 <- html_nodes(sample,".product-page__price__old") %>%
  html_text()
  df <- cbind(scrape1, scrape2, scrape3)
  final_df <- as.data.frame(df)
return(final_df)
}
```

data <- lapply(urls_all, func)